# Can Websphere Liberty features access all JNDI objects as OSGi services?

Tags: websphere-liberty

The [Websphere Liberty documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_feature_jndi.html) says that JNDI objects can be registered and retrieved as OSGi services by Liberty features.

Is this general to all JNDI objects (so, for instance, a session bean in an application could be discovered), or does it only apply to the objects that are registered to JNDI by using the OSGi registration method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects bound in the default JNDI namespace are available from the OSGi service registry, but it is not true for other namespaces.  In particular, session EJBs are only bound in the `java:` namespace, not the default namespace, so they are not available as OSGi services.

Comment: Thank you! That fits with my experimentation.